# How to copy HTML content with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to send an email, which is done with HTML and CSS, with Selenium, it appears that it can't get the page itself, only the text, or the code, so is there a way to copy the page.

Tried:

1. Sending Keys, (Keys.CONTROL + 'A').... (Keys.CONTROL + 'C') and assigning it to a var but didn't get what I want.
2. Constructing a field in the beginning and manually copy the content and paste it in the field, then getting its value, but same thing, it only gets the text.

Comment: You want to print the text on the web page?

Comment: no I want to send an email with an html content, so that I can make more designs with css and html, you know ...

Comment: For Those who don't know, you can copy a page content and send it in an email, with all its functions and design

Comment: Can you show the code which you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to get the `outerHTML` attribute from the target element.

Let's say you want to store all the HTML content (tags and text) from the `contentEmail` ID:

```
<div id="contentEmail">
   <span>
     My content email here!
     <br>
   </span>
</div>
```

To do this, you need this:

```
html_content = self.find_element(By.ID, "contentEmail").get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(html_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it,

the Sending Keys,

`(Keys.CONTROL + 'A')`

`(Keys.CONTROL + 'C')` worked but I just needed to send `(Keys.CONTROL + 'V')` Not assigning it to a `var`

Comment: Why would you do that ? You can get page resource in Selenium as well.

Comment: ok you can answer, and I will see if it is a more productive way

Comment: I need to copy HTML + CSS Page to send it in an email, is there a better way